# Storing PHP Variable from HTML Text Input Field

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap, variables, input

I've been bashing my head against a desk for awhile over this one and my brain is mush from reading tons of stuff and not having anything work.

Basically, I need to take the input from an html input field, assign it to a php variable, then append that variable to the end of a url.  I'm not having much luck at all so far!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>MyPage</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/themes/black-tie/jquery-ui.min.css">
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="//oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
      <script src="//oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.3.0/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <!-- Sorry this is so ugly, I was trying to get it done fast, I can make another pass and smack it with a pretty stick later -->
  <body>
  <div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="container">
      <h1>My Super Page</h1>
      <form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>">
        <p class="lead">Please Enter Some Text: </p>
        <input type="text" name="input">
        <input type="submit" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
      </form>
      <!-- Modal -->
      <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
              <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Results</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              Your Input Parsed:
              <?php
              $myInput = $_POST["input"];
              echo $myInput; 
              $service_url = 'http://www.myapiservice/index.php/api/lookup?key=notreal&number='. $myInput;
              $curl = curl_init($service_url);
              curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
              $curl_response = curl_exec($curl);
              if ($curl_response === false) {
                  $info = curl_getinfo($curl);
                  curl_close($curl);
                  die('error occured during curl exec. Additional info: ' . var_export($info));
              }
              curl_close($curl);
              echo $name;
              $decoded = json_decode($curl_response, true);
              if (isset($decoded->response->status) && $decoded->response->status == 'ERROR') {
                  die('error occured: ' . $decoded->response->errormessage);
              }
              $myVar = $decoded["Response"]["dataset"];
              if($myVar){
                echo $myVar;
              }
              else {
                echo 'Discarded Data';
              }

              ?>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
          </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
        </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
      </div><!-- /.modal -->
    </div>
  </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: So what happens once you submit the form?

Comment: In which line do you want to add the variable. Also please post only relevant code as it's very difficult to figure out your problem in such a large code.

Comment: I need to add <text_field_input> to the end of: $service_url = 'http://www.myapiservice/index.php/api/lookup?key=notreal&number=';

That's all I really need.  The rest of the code works perfectly as intended, I just need to be able to append the text to the end of the API url.

Comment: PHP is a server side language. That means that, unlike you may expect, things are only evaluated once and then sent to your browser. Once the info is sent to your browser (that is, once you see it) PHP will forget about it, and that's all. Have you tried submitting your form?. It is not until your code is evaluated again (this time with user input) that you may able to see the results.

Comment: From my understanding, the reasoning behind using POST  is it allows it to be updating after page load (in the case of reading input from a text field).


I have submitted it close to 100 times so far with various tweaks, and have no luck getting it to update correctly.  I really tried to avoid asking the question on here but got frustrated after 8 hours of reading and trying code snippets with no break through.

Comment: The most frustrating part is I'm able to make it work just fine in JavaScript/jQuery, but I'm having Cross Domain issues and the server doesn't support JSONP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using modalbox for input `type=submit`. So it is not send your data after click on submit.

I have modified submit button and open modal box upon submit button using `javascript.`

Here is your code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>MyPage</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/themes/black-tie/jquery-ui.min.css">
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://jquery-jsonp.googlecode.com/files/jquery.jsonp-1.0.4.min.js"></script>
    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="//oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
      <script src="//oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.3.0/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>


  <!-- Sorry this is so ugly, I was trying to get it done fast, I can make another pass and smack it with a pretty stick later -->
  <body>
  <div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="container">
      <h1>My Super Page</h1>
      <form method="get" action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>">
        <p class="lead">Please Enter Some Text: </p>
        <input type="text" name="input">
        <input type="submit">
      </form>

       <?php if(isset($_REQUEST['input'])){?>
  <script>
    $(function() {
          $( "#myModal" ).modal('show');   
    });
  </script>
  <?php }?>

      <!-- Modal -->
      <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
              <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Results</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              Your Input Parsed:
              <?php
              $myInput = $_REQUEST['input'];
              echo $myInput; 
              $service_url = 'http://www.myapiservice/index.php/api/lookup?key=notreal&number='. $myInput;
              $curl = curl_init($service_url);
              curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
              $curl_response = curl_exec($curl);
              if ($curl_response === false) {
                  $info = curl_getinfo($curl);
                  curl_close($curl);
                  die('error occured during curl exec. Additional info: ' . var_export($info));
              }
              curl_close($curl);
              echo $name;
              $decoded = json_decode($curl_response, true);
              if (isset($decoded->response->status) && $decoded->response->status == 'ERROR') {
                  die('error occured: ' . $decoded->response->errormessage);
              }
              $myVar = $decoded["Response"]["dataset"];
              if($myVar){
                echo $myVar;
              }
              else {
                echo 'Discarded Data';
              }

              ?>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
          </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
        </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
      </div><!-- /.modal -->
    </div>
  </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Gowri I wish I could vote you up 100 times, thank you for resolving this!  I actually meant to edit that line half a dozen times but kept running myself in circles with other solutions!